# Ajax form gets submitted twice when i click on submit button second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, validation

Simple bootstrap 5 (with validation) **contact form** with Ajax call gets executed only when i hit submit button second time and it also save data twice. this form is inside modal form and this behavior happened when i added Ajax function to code..

I am not sure what is stopping form submission successfully after validation, form gets submitted only when i hit submit button second time and it save same data twice.

based on references i used `e.stopImmediatePropagation();` but there behavior didnt change

```
<!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal-form modal fade" id="modal-form" data-bs-backdrop="static" tabindex="-1"
    aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Register you interest</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-body">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-holder">
                <div class="form-content">
                  <div class="form-items">

                    <p>Fill in the details below, we will get back to you!</p>
                    <form id="contactForm" class="requires-validation" action="sendemail.php"  method="POST" novalidate >

                      <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" required>
                         <div class="valid-feedback">Full Name field is valid!</div>
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">Full Name field cannot be blank!</div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
                        <input id="phone" type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control"
                          onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" required>
                        <div class="valid-feedback phoneinvalid" id="phoneinvalid"></div> 
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">Phone field cannot be blank!</div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
                      </div>



                      <div class="form-button mt-3">
                        <button id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-success-msg"></div>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<!-- Modal -->
```

JS Part

```
(function () {
'use strict'
const forms = document.querySelectorAll('.requires-validation')
Array.from(forms)
  .forEach(function (form) {
    form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log("form.checkValidity() "+form.checkValidity());
      if (!form.checkValidity()) {
       // form.classList.remove('was-validated')
        //event.preventDefault();
        //event.stopPropagation();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        form.classList.add('was-validated')
        return;
      }
      else
      {
          console.log("This line should execute only if Form is validated");
      AjaxCallSaveData();
      form.classList.add('was-validated')
      }
    }, false)
  })
})();

function AjaxCallSaveData() 
{
  console.log(" I am AjaxCall Function");
  $("form").submit(function (event) {
    
    var formData = {
      name: $("#name").val(),
      phone: $("#phone").val(),
      message: $("#message").val(),
      
    };
    
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "SaveData.php",
      data: formData,
      dataType: "json",
      encode: true
    }).done(function (data) {
      console.log(data);

      if (!data.success) {
        console.log("alert alert-warning");
        
      } else {
        console.log("alert alert-success");
        $(".form-success-msg").add("display","block");
        $("form").html(
          '<div class="alert alert-success">' + data.message + "</div>"
        );
      }


    });

    event.preventDefault();
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi, remove this `$("form").submit(function (event) {` event handler as you already have one and you are calling your function `AjaxCallSaveData ` from there .

Comment: It works after i comment code as mentioned by you, it saving data in database but `console.log(data);` `console.log("name "+ name);` dont show any data even though its save in data.

Comment: Is your server return value ? Are you sure you have `200` status for ajax ? Go inside your network tab -> XHR see what it return back.

Comment: Thanks swati, i had actually field name wrong in PHP file which was causing issue as it was not showing any error or data, once i corrected the field name it worked